# Allowing `SELECT` Privileges on all tables in schema including new tables created by different users (AWS RDS; PostgreSQL 11)

Tags: postgresql

I have a `readonly` user that I defined as the following:

```
CREATE ROLE readonly;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE dbname TO readonly;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonly;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema_name TO readonly;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name TO readonly;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema_name GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly;
```

I am currently running these commands as the `postgres` user who is the `rds_superuser` (I'm using AWS RDS). This works fine, and allows `readonly` role to read existing tables that `postgres` user creates, and also any new tables that `postgres` creates. However, when a new role creates a table, `readonly` cannot `SELECT` the table that the new role creates. For example, I also have a `readwrite` role, and tables created in that schema by `readwrite` cannot be `SELECT` by `readonly`.

[How do you create a read-only user in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760210/how-do-you-create-a-read-only-user-in-postgresql) suggests that by default `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES ...`  only works by default on objects created by the user that issued the command.

How can I more generally just allow `readonly` user to have `SELECT` privileges on ANY table created in the schema regardless of who creates it.

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63192368/1048572) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19309416/1048572). I don't think there's a catch-all though, even if you are a superuser.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the default privileges for any potential creator, e.g. for your `readwrite` role, use the following

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for role readwrite
    IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly;
```

Comment: Thanks! The way I have it set up is I only have two roles: `readwrite` and `readonly`. However, I then create separate user logins for each person on my team. So let's say I have `User1` and `User2`. I then granted the roles to each user (e.g. `GRANT readwrite to USER1`). The behavior I found was User1 would create the table, and I actually ran the statement you posted above. I had assumed since User1 had the readwrite role, the statement you posted above would work. However, this was not the case, I actually had to run something like `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for USER User1 ...` Why is that?

Comment: Would it be better practice if I have a team that I don't actually create different users for each team member? I just have everyone login to the same `readwrite` role?